# started learning node cluster getting error

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing

**I tried this as my first code and i am getting error**

```
   const cluster = require('cluster');
    const http = require('http');
    const numCPUs = 4;

    if (cluster.isMaster) {
      // Fork workers.
      for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
      }
       cluster.on('online', function(worker) {
            console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' is online');
        });

      cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
        console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
      });

    } else {
      // Workers can share any TCP connection
      // In this case it is an HTTP server
      http.createServer((req, res) => {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end('hello world\n');
      }).listen(8000);
    }
```

This is the Error i am getting :-

Worker 11056 is online
Worker 11057 is online
Worker 11058 is online
Worker 11059 is online
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: bind EADDRINUSE null:8000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at cb (net.js:1302:16)
    at rr (cluster.js:594:14)
    at Worker. (cluster.js:564:9)
    at process. (cluster.js:714:8)
    at emitTwo (events.js:92:20)
    at process.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at handleMessage (internal/child_process.js:689:10)
    at Pipe.channel.onread (internal/child_process.js:440:11)
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: bind EADDRINUSE null:8000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at cb (net.js:1302:16)
    at rr (cluster.js:594:14)
    at Worker. (cluster.js:564:9)
    at process. (cluster.js:714:8)
    at emitTwo (events.js:92:20)
    at process.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at handleMessage (internal/child_process.js:689:10)
    at Pipe.channel.onread (internal/child_process.js:440:11)
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: bind EADDRINUSE null:8000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at cb (net.js:1302:16)
    at rr (cluster.js:594:14)
    at Worker. (cluster.js:564:9)
    at process. (cluster.js:714:8)
    at emitTwo (events.js:92:20)
    at process.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at handleMessage (internal/child_process.js:689:10)
    at Pipe.channel.onread (internal/child_process.js:440:11)
worker 11056 died
worker 11057 died
worker 11058 died
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: bind EADDRINUSE null:8000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at cb (net.js:1302:16)
    at rr (cluster.js:594:14)
    at Worker. (cluster.js:564:9)
    at process. (cluster.js:714:8)
    at emitTwo (events.js:92:20)
    at process.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at handleMessage (internal/child_process.js:689:10)
    at Pipe.channel.onread (internal/child_process.js:440:11)
worker 11059 died

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EADDRINUSE` means that something else is already bound to the port/IP address combination that you are trying to use.

Things to check:

- Do you already have some other process binding to port 8000? If so, perhaps change the port number in your code here.
- Do you have another instance of this code running? (On UNIX-like operating systems, perhaps use `ps` with appropriate options to find it.) If so, terminate the other instance. (On UNIX-like operating systems, you might use `kill` or `pkill` with appropriate options.)

Comment: I've updated my answer with suggestions. (My very first answer was basically wrong, sorry about that. I've removed the incorrect information. There isn't an error in your code. My mistake.)

Comment: There is no other process using this port 8000. I have tried changing ports, now it is working

Answer (score 1):

Are you starting your server somewhere else in your project?

Try splitting your new worker creation out into a separate file.

**worker.js**

```
import express from 'express';
  http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('hello world\n');
  }).listen(8000);
```

And directing server setup to this file

***setup.js***

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const http = require('http');
const numCPUs = 4;

cluster.setupMaster({
  exec: __dirname + '/worker.js'
});

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Fork workers.
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
     cluster.fork();
  }
  cluster.on('online', function(worker) {
     console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' is online');
   });

  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
   });
   return 1;
}
```